# What is the benefit of vSphere Standard from free ESXi if vCenter Center is still sold separately?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I'm trying to understand what is what in their vSphere suite.

So, `ESXi` has a free edition --- I can install it and use it with `vSphere Web Client`.

But when I buy `vSphere Standard` --- what else do I get if `vCenter Server` is not included?

For example, `HA`, `DP` and `FT` --- are they even accessible without the `vCS`?

Or the whole purpose of a single vSphere license is to build a single VM unit controllable by a separate vCS instance (bought separately)?

Comment: You're missing the vSphere Essentials bundle. That includes vCenter and licenses for 6 CPU sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point to buying vSphere Standard (or any SKU) without vCenter Server or the vCenter Appliance.

If you don't have a previous vSphere purchase on record, vCenter and vSphere licenses can usually be acquired in a bundle at a discount.

Answer (score 0):

ESXi Free edition is also limited to an host with no more than 32 GB of RAM.